# How to perform term aggregation based on Url Domain name using Nest ElasticClient

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I want perform aggregation on a uri field, but return only the domain part of the url rather than full url. For example, with the field, `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?guided=true` I would get `stackoverflow.com`
Given an existing dataset as follows:

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "people",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "L9WewGoBZqCeOmbRIMlV",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "firstName" : "George",
          "lastName" : "Ouma",
          "pageUri" : "http://www.espnfc.com/story/683732/england-football-team-escaped-terrorist-attack-at-1998-world-cup",
          "date" : "2019-05-16T12:29:08.1308177Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "people",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "MNWewGoBZqCeOmbRIsma",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "firstName" : "George",
          "lastName" : "Ouma",
          "pageUri" : "http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Terrorism_in_Mexico",
          "date" : "2019-05-16T12:29:08.1308803Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "people",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2V-ewGoBiHg_1GebJKIr",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "firstName" : "George",
          "lastName" : "Ouma",
          "pageUri" : "http://www.wikipedia.com/story/683732/england-football-team-escaped-terrorist-attack-at-1998-world-cup",
          "date" : "2019-05-16T12:29:08.1308811Z"
        }
      }
    ]
```

My bucket should be as follows:

```
"buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "www.espnfc.com",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "www.wikipedia.com",
          "doc_count" : 2
        }
      ]
```

I have the following code snippet on how i do the aggregation, however this aggregates based on full url rather than domain name

```cs
var searchResponse = client.Search<Person>(s =>
    s.Size(0)

    .Query(q => q
        .MatchAll()
    )
    .Aggregations(a => a
        .Terms("visited_pages", ta => ta
            .Field(f => f.PageUri.Suffix("keyword"))
        )
    )
);

var aggregations = searchResponse.Aggregations.Terms("visited_pages");
```

Any assistance will be gratefully appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made use of the below [Terms Aggregation using Script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html).

Note that, looking at your data, I've come up with the string logic. Do test it and modify the logic based on what you are looking for.

*Best approach would be try to have a separate field called `hostname` with the values of what you are looking for and apply aggregation on top of it.*

However, if you are stuck, I suppose below aggregation can help!!

### Aggregation Query:

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "my_unique_urls": {
      "terms": {
        "script" : {
          "inline": """
            String st = doc['pageUri.keyword'].value;
            if(st==null){
              return "";
            } else {
              return st.substring(0, st.lastIndexOf(".")+4);
            }
          """,
          "lang": "painless"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Below is how my response appears:

### Query Response:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 4,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "my_unique_urls": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "http://www.espnfc.com",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "http://www.wikipedia.org",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "https://en.wikipedia.org",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot @kamal. This really do work on the console. Do you have an idea how i can write the same script on Nest?
Otherwise, without Nest, this would be the accepted answer.

Comment: Sorry @georgeouma, I am not a C# developer but this link should help you https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/terms-aggregation-usage.html#_object_initializer_syntax_example_146

Comment: You can copy past the script mentioned above in this line `Script = new InlineScript("<the_above_script>")` and see if this works. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks a bunch mate

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend breaking that data out into another field (something like "topleveldomain") during ingestion, otherwise Elasticsearch has to do a lot of work for each document before it can do the aggregation.

Comment: Thanks a lot @joe-zack for taking your valuable time to respond. This a good suggestion. However, am aggregating over already existing index containing millions of documents. What do you think would the best way to go about such a scenario?